# gerrit error : Nonetype object has no attribute split

Tags: python, gerrit, attributeerror

I am creating local repository for gerrit.

when I execute the command :

```
git-review -s
```

it gives me error as :

```
branch_parts = branch_name.split("/")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

can anyone let me know how to solve the same?

Comment: The error says that `branch_name = None`. Did you name your branch?

Comment: actually I am using it first time so I dont have idea how to create it. can u help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if your value is `None`

```
In [119]: branch_name = None

In [120]: branch_parts = branch_name.split("/")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/avasal/<ipython console> in <module>()

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Make sure the value in `branch_name` is as expected